# How do I serialize a Dictionary<int, string>?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I serialize a C# `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: Can you please give some details regarding how you want it serialized? Xml? Binary? Anything?

Comment: The JSON.Net Library is also a very good alternative, :D

Comment: If you want to use JSON take a look here: http://www.jarloo.com/serialize-to-json/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple demo:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, string>();

lookup.Add(1, "123");
lookup.Add(2, "456");

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var formatter = 
       new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

    formatter.Serialize(ms, lookup);
    lookup = null;

    ms.Position = 0;
    lookup = (Dictionary<int, string>) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
}

foreach(var i in lookup.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, lookup[i]);
}
```

But you probably have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about XML serialization, you could use Paul Welter's `SerializableDictionary` class, as suggested by Kevin, but here's another solution, not involving a custom implementation of `IXmlSerializable`.

My idea is that a dictionary can be seen as a collection of key-value pairs. `XmlSerializer` can serialize a collection, and it can serialize a key-value pair. So you just have to create a wrapper for the dictionary, that appears to be a collection so that `XmlSerializer` will handle it without complaining.

Here's my implementation :

A `XmlDictionaryEntry` class to hold the key-value pair (the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` class can't be serialized to XML because its properties are read-only)

```
public class XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

A `XmlDictionaryEntryCollection` class, implementing a collection of key-value pairs and using a dictionary to store them

```
public class XmlDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey, TValue> : ICollection<XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public XmlDictionaryEntryCollection()
    {
        this.Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public XmlDictionaryEntryCollection(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        dictionary.CheckArgumentNull("dictionary");
        this.Dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary { get; private set; }

    #region ICollection<XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey,TValue>> Members

    public void Add(XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        this.Dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.Dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return this.Dictionary.ContainsKey(item.Key);
    }

    public void CopyTo(XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        int index = arrayIndex;
        if (arrayIndex + this.Dictionary.Count > array.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException(ExceptionMessages.CopyToNotEnoughSpace);

        foreach (var kvp in this.Dictionary)
        {
            var entry = new XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue>
            {
                Key = kvp.Key,
                Value = kvp.Value
            };
            array[index++] = entry;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.Dictionary.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return this.Dictionary.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return this.Dictionary.Remove(item.Key);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey,TValue>> Members

    public IEnumerator<XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in this.Dictionary)
        {
            yield return new XmlDictionaryEntry<TKey, TValue>
            {
                Key = kvp.Key,
                Value = kvp.Value
            };
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

An extension method to make it easier to create the wrapper (taking advantage of generic type inference) :

```
public static class XmlSerializationExtension()
{
    public static XmlDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey, TValue> AsXmlSerializable<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary != null)
            return new XmlDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Here's how you use it :

Assuming you have this property :

```
public Dictionary<string, Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

You just need to hide that property from the serializer (using the `XmlIgnore` attribute), and serialize a `XmlDictionaryEntryCollection` instead :

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Dictionary<string, Foo> Foos { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Foos")]
public XmlDictionaryEntryCollection SerializableFoos
{
    get { return Foos.AsXmlSerializable(); }
    set { Foos = value.Dictionary; }
}
```

The main benefit of this technique over the `SerializableDictionary` class is that it lets you use any kind of dictionary you want, you're not stuck with a specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own object which has the following two methods, Serialize and DeSerialize.  Form_Load is used for testing

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> list = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        list.Add(1, "one");
        list.Add(2, "two");
        list.Add(3, "three");

        Dictionary<int, string> list2 = Deserialize(Serialize(list));

    }

    public  string Serialize(Dictionary<int, string> classObject)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        output.Append("<DictionaryIntString>");

        foreach (int key in classObject.Keys)
        {
            output.Append(String.Format("<Key value=\"{0}\">",key));
            output.Append(String.Format("<Value>{0}</Value></Key>", classObject[key]));

        }
        output.Append("</DictionaryIntString>");
        return output.ToString();


    }

    public Dictionary<int, string> Deserialize(string input)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> output = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(input);

        foreach (XmlNode node in xml.GetElementsByTagName("Key"))
        {
            output.Add(Int32.Parse(node.Attributes["value"].InnerText),node.FirstChild.InnerText);

        }

        return output;
    }
}
```